# Windows 10, frequent system "progressive" crashes (already tried a lot ...)

Tags: windows-10, crash

### How it started

In March 2017, Win10 had recurring BSODs and, at some point, could not start at all. I did a reinstallation from the Win10 "repair tool". BSODs remained. Then I did a fresh install from Win10 DVD (which was a pre-Anniversary version). In the meantime I updated as many BIOS, firmwares, divers as I could. And I never had a BSOD since, but …

### Symptoms of current problem

Apparently only after the Anniversary update: After some very random time but most often 15 to 45 minutes (and not necessarily increasing or decreasing with occurrences), both sound cards start to make a regular noise over any sound they're playing, one RANDOM application crashes (not responding), other open applications keep running but progressively, clicks here and there start having no effect at all. TaskBar also progressively crashes. New windows or menus don’t appear. CTRL+ALT+DEL not working, Start Menu not working.

So thins looks to me like the crash comes from somewhere in Windows 10 UI.

At the end of this progressive crash, that only option is a hard "Power off". (Making post-crash diagnostics harder.)

### Hardwares

- CPU: Intel Core I7 6700K
- MB: Asus Maximum VIII Extreme
- GPU: Asus Strix Nvidia GTX 980
- RAM : G.SKILL Trident Z DRR4 3000 C15 2x16Gb
- PSU: Corsair AX860
- System Disk: Samsung 850 Pro 512GB
- Second work disk: Samsung 850 Pro 512GB
- Larger data disk: Western Digital Caviar Black 6GB
- Extra soundcard: Asus Xonar Essence STX
- DVD burner: Plextor PX-820SA
- Extra data diskd: 4 hard drive slots in front of the case (using mostly Western Digital)
- OS: Windows 10 Pro
- Monitors: 2x 4K Benq BL2711U + 1x Full HD Sony television

### Softwares

**Softwares I typically install:** Eset NOD32 (anti virus), Magix Vegas Pro 13 (with Hitfilm plug-ins), Magix SoundForge 11, Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 6, Visual Studio Community 2017, Notepad++, Microsoft Office 2010 (because I paid for that one and I don’t see the point updating yet), Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Mozilla Thunderbird, Foobar2000, FileZilla, MozBackup, WinMerge, WinDirStart, CritalDiskInfo, hwMonitor,  …

**Softwares I typically install but were not installed yet when crashes already happened:** VLC, Adobe Photoshop, …

**Softwares I typically uninstall**: OneDrive, games coming with Windows, NVidia Geforce Experience

### Things already tried

I’ve tried so many that I’m not sure if the list will be exhaustive:

- Tested memory: OK
- Tested hard drives: OK
- Checked that nothing is overheating
- Deactivating things such as "Turbo modes" in BIOS
- Analysed Event Viewer, tried to correct failures (like service trying to launch but not having the right to, which seems "normal" since Win10 Anniversary) but that didn’t impact the recurring problem.
- Re-analysed Event Viewer and realized that the recurring crashes are NOT correlated with any Event Viewer failure entries.
- Used Microsoft Windows Malicious Software Removal (fast mode only so far)
- Deactivating Real-time system protection of Eset NOD32
- Tried running without the extra sound card.
- Tried running without any extra hard drive.
- Reinstalled directly Windows 10 version 1703 (in case problem was due to the act of updating to Anniversary).

### Question

Any idea how I could diagnose this further ?

---

### Current experiment

On 26/5/2017 I started a very "slow" step-by-step re-installation. Timestamps relate to the line before them. Current stat no real crash yet:

20170526 1848~

- Desktop icon
- Drive letters corrected
- Installed GPU Nvidia drivers 382.05
- Installed Notepad++
- Installed WinRAR x64
- Changed File explorer display
- Installed Mozilla Firefox
- Installed Google Chrome
- Installed .NET Fx 3.5 (recommended as a fix to some Windows crashes and for 
  Magix Sound Forge)
- Installed Magix_Vegas_Pro_13_build_545_x64
- Install Magix_Sound_Forge_Pro_11_build_345
- Installed HitFilm Plugins 3.1.5213.10801 x64 (plug-ins I use in Vegas)
- Installed NewBlueVideoEssentials6VegasPro13ForWindowsSetup30 (plug-ins I use in Vegas)

20170526 1900~
 - PC Renamed
 - Set PC power management to "High Performance". Never goes to sleep.

20170526 2000~

- Reinstalled my font collection (1574 fonts in total, used in various projects)

20170526 2045~

- Restart

20170527 0548~

- Installed GPU Nvidia drivers 382.33

20170527 1200~

- Installed MozBackup
- Installed Mozilla Thunderbird

20170527 1705

- Installed VLC
- Installed Foobar2000

20170528 ~2100

- Installed Motherboard audio drivers

20170529 1953

- Disabled stuff in Star Up (Adobe Creative Cloud, Adobe Updated Startup Utility, Microsoft One Drive, NVIDIA Capture Server Proxy, SS2UILauncher.exe, SVLoadSense
- Disabled Windows 10 cosmetics options
- Installed Motherboard SATA drivers
- Restart

20170530 0018

- !! Weird: Ran Windows Maliciaous Software Tool (May 2017) during the night, in the morning, its windows had disappear and the sound card making the "crash noise"
  (Other two, older computer were clean.)

20170530 ~0700

30/5/2017: At this point, I'd suspect the SATA drivers ? Possibly the audio drivers ? Disabling One Drive ??? Or yet the fact of scanning some file ?

Softwares not installed yet and that I suspected to be related to the issue: Office 2010, Eset NOD32 (anti-virus)

Comment: share the dmp files that Windows creates after BSOD so that we can debug it to see which issue you have. upload the mto onedrive and post a share link here.

Comment: If you read what I wrote: I didn't have a BSOD since March and the drive has been formated multiple times sinces.

Comment: try to [generate dumps for the user mode Applications](https://pastebin.com/zKuJvw57) that crash and share those dumps