# Windows 10 cannot shut down

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

After recent Windows 10 update, windows will not shut down. It turn black as if shutting down but after that the computer stays on and go to login screen.

(Same if I shut down from start menu of login screen.)

**Event Views - System Error matching shut down time**
All Event ID 10016

> The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local
>   Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
>   {6B3B8D23-FA8D-40B9-8DBD-B950333E2C52}  and APPID 
>   {4839DDB7-58C2-48F5-8283-E1D1807D0D7D}  to the user NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL
>   SERVICE SID (S-1-5-19) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in
>   the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security
>   permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative
>   tool.
>
> The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local
>   Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
>   {6B3B8D23-FA8D-40B9-8DBD-B950333E2C52}  and APPID 
>   {4839DDB7-58C2-48F5-8283-E1D1807D0D7D}  to the user NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL
>   SERVICE SID (S-1-5-19) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in
>   the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security
>   permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative
>   tool.
>
> The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local
>   Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
>   {D63B10C5-BB46-4990-A94F-E40B9D520160}  and APPID 
>   {9CA88EE3-ACB7-47C8-AFC4-AB702511C276}  to the user PC20151118\User
>   SID (S-1-5-21-679355930-4074167791-2210837944-1001) from address
>   LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container
>   Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be
>   modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

**Event Views - Application errors matching shut down time**

All are Event Id 1000.

> Faulting application name: ATKEX_cmd.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time
>   stamp: 0x00000000 Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
>   10.0.16299.15, time stamp: 0x2cd1ce3d Exception code: 0x0eedfade Fault offset: 0x001008b2 Faulting process ID: 0x2968 Faulting application
>   start time: 0x01d37a837c3c0072 Faulting application path: C:\Program
>   Files\Realtek\Audio\HDA\ATKEX_cmd.exe Faulting module path:
>   C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll Report ID:
>   6522abdd-536a-42f8-8c2d-ec401419f07a Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:
>
> Faulting application name: ATKEX_cmd.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time
>   stamp: 0x00000000 Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
>   10.0.16299.15, time stamp: 0x2cd1ce3d Exception code: 0x0eedfade Fault offset: 0x001008b2 Faulting process ID: 0x2968 Faulting application
>   start time: 0x01d37a837c3c0072 Faulting application path: C:\Program
>   Files\Realtek\Audio\HDA\ATKEX_cmd.exe Faulting module path:
>   C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll Report ID:
>   fb8a4681-c381-40c1-b387-7044e688f084 Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:
>
> Faulting application name: ATKEX_cmd.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time
>   stamp: 0x00000000 Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
>   10.0.16299.15, time stamp: 0x2cd1ce3d Exception code: 0x0eedfade Fault offset: 0x001008b2 Faulting process ID: 0x1650 Faulting application
>   start time: 0x01d37a837dd3217d Faulting application path: C:\Program
>   Files\Realtek\Audio\HDA\ATKEX_cmd.exe Faulting module path:
>   C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll Report ID:
>   aa6f3581-1384-4225-9b08-f9f0558aec3a Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:
>
> Faulting application name: ATKEX_cmd.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time
>   stamp: 0x00000000 Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
>   10.0.16299.15, time stamp: 0x2cd1ce3d Exception code: 0x0eedfade Fault offset: 0x001008b2 Faulting process ID: 0x1650 Faulting application
>   start time: 0x01d37a837dd3217d Faulting application path: C:\Program
>   Files\Realtek\Audio\HDA\ATKEX_cmd.exe Faulting module path:
>   C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll Report ID:
>   638e0047-244b-48cb-8302-61b925fb6fa0 Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

**Somewhat reminds me of this question:** [Windows 10, frequent system "progressive" crashes (already tried a lot ...)](https://superuser.com/questions/1213113/windows-10-frequent-system-progressive-crashes-already-tried-a-lot)

Which I never truly answered but solved by NOT installing Asus motherboard drivers (I kept those provided when installing Windows).
The relation may be unclear as the other question doesn't have Event Viewer entries but there where also many app/services "security permission" issues.

**Tried:** sfc /scannow: "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violation."

**Trying** : Looks like the issue may come from Asus Realtek Audio drivers. (I also have Asos Xonar Essence STX in the computer. Uninstalled and deleted from computer Asus Realtek Audio drivers, restarted, managed to shutdown before login. But after login Windows automatically reinstalls them. Tried with the device turn off but this way is still blocking, might try to install new drivers version.
Otherwise, how can I prevent widnows from reinstalling the drivers ?

**Tried** Asus drivers latest version: still preventing Windows from shutting down.

**Tried further**: Computer's properties > Advanced system setings > Hardware > Device Installation Settings > **No** . Then disable Realtek Audio. Then uninstalled + deleted drivers. Then reboot. Tried to shut down from login screen (before login) failed (while according to previous tests I expected it to work). Logged in again: Windows reinstalled the drivers anyway (latest version).

Comment: Start by looking into your Event Viewer for messages around the time you initiate the shutdown. Also, try shutting down by command: "shutdown -t 01" and see what happens. That command literally means "shutdown in 1 second".

Comment: Thank you. Showing Event Viewer entries here is on of my next step (but I'm quite in a hurry at the moment).  "shutdown -t 01" display shutdown help. "shutdown /s" actually succeed shutting down the computer.

Comment: Good, until you solve the problem put that command in a .bat file and place it on your desktop and just double-click to shutdown. As for the Event Viewer: There are many reasons why you may not be able to shut down, far too many for us to narrow down based on the information you've given us so far. We will need to see that information from the Event Viewer to narrow down the possible causes.

Comment: Yes, I did a batch file. Using it also required to run it as administrator (otherwise it endlessly write "shutdown /s" in command prompt.
I added Event Viewer entries to this question.

Comment: Tried: sfc /scannow: "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violation."

Comment: Have you removed the ASUS mainboard and Realtek audio drivers and installed the latest versions?

Comment: That is what I was trying as you were writing, please check the question's last update (at bottom of the question).

Comment: Windows will only auto install if the version installed is older than the version Microsoft finds in its repository. So go to the ASUS site and get the latest version and install it manually.

Comment: I tried it, no success. Please check the question's last two updates. (I will have to go, so I'll have to come back to this later.)

Comment: Does a reboot occur normally? If so, this is likely a glitch with "Fast Startup" and your BIOS/UEFI firmware. Go into Power Options and disable "Turn on Fast Startup (recommended)" and retest. Link from Acer, not platform specific but their's is very simple to follow: https://in.answers.acer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/37059/~/windows-10%3A-enable-or-disable-fast-startup

Comment: Thank you. It looks like this works. And the PC never shut down so fast.
I suggest you write it as "answer" so I can select it as the solution.

Answer (score -3):

'windows cannot be shutdown' i have some solutions that might work.
solution one hold down the power button for 10 seconds. 
another solution that may work is pulling out the plug for 10 seconds.
please let me know if this helps.

Peace out.
source
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4036280/surface-force-a-shut-down-and-restart-your-surface
also works with windows.

Comment: These force a power off of your computer. OP was specifically asking about shutting down the OS, which is different.